# SpeechSynthesis API's getVoices method not working properly (returning EMPTY array)

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, voice, speech-synthesis

When I was using the speechSynthesis API, I came across a problem when I attempted to change the voice of the speech utterance from the default voice.

I used the following code:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    
msg.voice = voices[2];
msg.text = "Hello World!";
speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

The above code was supposed to change the voice to "Microsoft Linda - English (Canada)", but it did NOT do this. **However**, when I executed the code **directly** in the developer console, the voice setting actually worked.

So, to investigate this, I checked the contents of the array that `getVoices()` returned, by doing this:

```
console.log(window.speechSynthesis.getVoices());
```

When I added this code in my HTML file, **an empty array was printed**.

When I executed this code directly in the developer console, **the intended array was printed**.

Why does this happen and how can I fix my code accordingly, such that I can change the `voice` property of the `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` object, without having to run the code directly in the developer's console?

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the issue. Apparently, `getVoices()` returned an empty array in the HTML file, because the program was invoking it **before** the voices loaded. So, I attached an `onvoiceschanged` event listener to `speechSynthesis`, which invokes the speech code, so that the speech code runs **after** the voices are loaded. This effectively worked and properly changed the voice.

Here is the final code:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    
speechSynthesis.addEventListener("voiceschanged", () => {
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        
    msg.voice = voices[2];
    msg.text = "Hello World!";
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
});
```

Therefore, the reason the original code worked in the developer's console is because the voices were already loaded there.